# c# wpf WebBrowser очень плохо прогружает страницу

Tags: c#, webbrowser

пытаюсь загрузить сайт `https://coub.com` в WebBrowser элементе.
и вот такой вид в итоге получают, вместо нормальной страницы
 [image: вот такой вид оно в итоге имеет]

возможно ли как-то сделать чтобы прогрузило нормально?
я смотрел варианты с заменой WebBrowser на что-то другое, но они как-то чересчур объёмные для моей задачи .. одно платное, другое с не открытыми исходниками и т.д.

Вообще задача показать пользователю окно входа в аккаунт, и после работать дальше со страничкой через HttpWebRequest. программа чисто для себя, "терять" / получать чужие куки не собираюсь ..

Comment: у куба есть апи, но они только для веб-приложений.
Так же показывать окно с браузером надо, потому-что там просит ввести капчу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в общем проблема была в том,что браузер работал с версией 7,вместо 11.. 
и я находил как сделать чтобы запускало всё таки с 11, но не работало (не работало потому-что изменял в не правильном месте реестр, т.е. система 64 битная, а менял для 32 битной..)

нашел решение [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25650219/6744352) , там же и расписано значения для разных версий браузера

```
private void SetIE11KeyforWebBrowserControl()
        {
            string appName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe"; 
            RegistryKey Regkey = null;
            try
            {
                // For 64 bit machine
                if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
                    Regkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\MAIN\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);
                else  //For 32 bit machine
                    Regkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);
                // If the path is not correct or
                // if the user haven't priviledges to access the registry
                if (Regkey == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Application Settings Failed - Address Not found");
                    return;
                }
                string FindAppkey = Convert.ToString(Regkey.GetValue(appName));
                // Check if key is already present
                if (FindAppkey == "11001")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Required Application Settings Present");
                    Regkey.Close();
                    return;
                }
                // If a key is not present add the key, Key value 11001 (decimal)
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FindAppkey))
                    Regkey.SetValue(appName, unchecked((int)0x2AF9), RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                // Check for the key after adding
                FindAppkey = Convert.ToString(Regkey.GetValue(appName));

                if (FindAppkey == "11001")
                    MessageBox.Show("Application Settings Applied Successfully");
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Application Settings Failed, Ref: " + FindAppkey);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Application Settings Failed");
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Close the Registry
                if (Regkey != null)
                    Regkey.Close();
            }
        }
```